# Using the same Count twice in one sql select

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sql-order-by

```
SELECT Person.name, Person.lastName, COUNT(DISTINCT childrenID) 
FROM Person, ParentChildren 
WHERE ParentChildren.parentID = ParentChildren.parentID 
AND Person.ID = ParentChildren.parentID 
GROUP BY COUNT(DISTINCT childrenID) DESC;
```

It obviously doesn't work, because I'm not good at this. 
What it should do is display name, last name and how many children the person have starting from person, with the most children.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your WHERE statement is incorrect. And you group by is also incorrect. You group by the columns that aren't being SUM'd, COUNT'd, etc.

```
WHERE ParentChildren.parentID = ParentChildren.parentID
```

If you switch this to the correct table join then you might get the answer you're looking for.
EDIT: After looking at the schematic I think this is what you're going for:

```
SELECT
  Person.name, 
  Person.lastName, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT ParentChildren.childrenID) 
FROM Person, ParentChildren 
WHERE 
  Person.ID = ParentChildren.parentID 
GROUP BY 
  Person.name,
  Person.lastName
ORDER BY
  COUNT(DISTINCT childrenID) DESC;
```

If you're receiving an error can you post it?

Comment: WHERE ParentChildren.parentID = ParentChildren.parentID  worked with other GROUP BY so I thought it was correct. Is there any other way to say that I need two fields with the same walue? In this case, the same parent can have more than one child, therefore, more than one record.

Comment: Well think about what it's doing. It's as good as saying WHERE 1=1 which is always true. Can you post your table schema? Without it I can't tell if you should be joining on parentID or ID.

Comment: @TylerFerraro It works. Thank you so much. Honestly, what you did looks like magic to me.

Comment: Look up how to join tables. You can continue doing it through WHERE but eventually with complex statements it's better to use LEFT JOIN, INNER JOIN, etc.